# MvcContrib Grid - Go to first page when sorting

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib

i am using the MvcContrib grid for an mvc application. 
I have set up sorting and paging , but I have to make the grid to go the first page when the user sorts the grid .

Any ideas on how doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could append an additional parameter to the sort action which is `currentPage` or whatever you use in your pager to track the current page and when generating this link set the parameter value to `1`. Also make sure that on the server side in the sorting action you are specifying the proper range when paging the data source (`.AsPagination(1, PAGE_SIZE)`).

Comment: How can i append some additional parameters, for current sorting ? I tried adding some hidden fields but when the users click on a column name to sort , the values didn't passed to the controller.

Comment: It depends how you handle the sort links. If you are using hyperlinks you will need to pass the parameters as query string when generating those links.

Comment: I use the links , that MvcContrib generates for sorting when adding the following at the grid: .Sort(ViewData["sort"] as GridSortOptions)

Comment: Any ideas on how to add the parameter with the previous sorting , so that if the sorting is different than the current i will redirect the user to page 1. 

PS:Maybe there are better approaches too.